# In which city are these buildings?

Tags: identify-this

[image]

Which city are the buildings on this picture in?

Comment: looks like a 3d rendering, not a photo ? do you have a source of this image ? if all fails, it might be in dubai or similar country

Comment: It's a snap from a movie that i came across and it's a real place

Comment: What movie is it?

Comment: And what time in the movies was this scene?

Comment: You might be better off asking this on our Movies and TV site. Also check the IMDB listing for the movie, as that usually tells you hwere it was filmed.

Comment: It was sort of a screensaver that was launched in a store,not a cinema movie

Comment: What makes you certain that it's a real place?

Comment: Cars,boats,palm trees moving in the wind,etc

Comment: @krokodyl , that doesn't mean a thing. Watch the latest Star Wars, more than half of it is CGI and does not exist in reality. I think it's computer generated because everything is too neat, clean, and orderly.

Comment: When it looks like an obvious rendering, 99% of the time is Dubai. Takes a lot of effort to take a picture of that city and have it not look like someone first render :-D

Comment: Dubai Marina tased from Apple TV screensaver

Answer (score 13, accepted):

It's Dubai Marina, but may I be damned if I can find a picture from the same position and angle.

This is the best I can find:
[image]

Comment: [Google Maps Streetview link](https://www.google.com/maps/@25.0757525,55.1366544,3a,60y,44.69h,91.15t/data=!3m6!1e1!3m4!1s9REDY_0FsfutnYjERipW0Q!2e0!7i13312!8i6656)